# Много шума при воспроизведении звука AudioSource (Unity)?

Tags: unity3d, аудио

Мне нужно проиграть `.mp3` файл (длительность ~1мин), но нужно проиграть его как `byte[]` которые я получаю от нативной либы. То есть флоу выглядит так `native decoder(MediaFoundataion) -> ConvertFromByteToFloat -> Playback(Unity)`.

Вот метод который я использую для конвертации

```
    private static float[] Convert16BitByteArrayToAudioClipData(byte[] source)
    {
        float[] data = new float[source.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = ((float)source[i] / Int16.MaxValue);
        }

        return data;
    }
```

И вот метод котой проигрывает звук

```
void playSound()
{
        // create audiosource object and audio clip
        if (audioSource == null)
        {
            audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            audioSource.pitch = audioPitch;
            audioSource.volume = audioVolume;
            audioSource.loop = audioLoop;
        }

        ((StreamCompositeWithAudio) stream).GetCharacteristics(
            ref mAudioSampleRate, 
            ref bitsPerSample, 
            ref mAudioChannels, 
            ref mAudioLengthSamples
        );

        if (audioClip == null && audioSource != null)
        {
            audioClip = AudioClip.Create("videoAudio", mAudioLengthSamples * 200 /*for test*/, (int)mAudioChannels, (int)mAudioSampleRate, false);
            audioSource.clip = audioClip;
        }

        if (audioSource.isPlaying == false)
        {
            audioSource.Play();
        }

        if (!once && isPlayAudio && stream is StreamCompositeWithAudio streamAudio)
        {
            once = true;
            float ptsSec = 0;
            int nSamples = 0;

            while (streamAudio.GetAudioClipData(ref ptsSec) && ptsSec < 200) // JUST FOR TEST
            {
                float[] data = streamAudio.GetAudioData();
                audioSource.clip.SetData(data, nSamples);
                nSamples += data.Length;
            }
        }
}
```

Когда вызываю `playSound()` метод, то я слышу голос и слова, но есть 2 проблемы -

1. Очень много шума, такое впечатление как будто слушаю старый приемник
2. Речь затянута, как будто жевачку тянут.

Насчет первого пункта, я думал, что может проблема в количестве каналов, но нет - у меня один канал и соответсвенно 1 я передаю как параметр. Откуда берется этот шум? Как можно это подебажить, чтоб понять?

и насчет второго пункта: `AudioClip.Create("AudioVoice", (int)(mAudioLengthSamples * justForTestNum * 1.2), (int)mAudioChannels, (int)(mAudioSampleRate), false);` и тут `mAudioSampleRate = 44100` если я умножаю этот параметр на 2 то эффект жевачки пропадает или `audioSource.pitch = audioPitch;` дефолтное значение 1, но если я передаю 2, то тоже эффект жевачки пропадает, но вопрос в том, почему мне нужно умножать это значение на 2? Если 44100 это мой стандартный сампл рейт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Речь затянута, как будто жевачку тянут.
>
> `mAudioSampleRate = 44100` если я умножаю этот параметр на 2 то эффект жевачки пропадает.

Потому что у вас 16-битный звук, а вы его переводите как 8-битный звук. В итоге каждый второй (или первый, зависит от порядка байт) результирующий байт несет испорченную информацию. Общее время звуковой дорожки увеличивается в 2 раза, именно поэтому "умножение" сэмплрейта на 2 решает проблему. Был бы у вас 64-битный звук, сэмплрейт нужно было бы увеличивать в 4 раза.

> Очень много шума, такое впечатление как будто слушаю старый приемник

Вы каждый байт `[0..255]` нормализуете значением `32767` и получаете очень "схожие" значения, например:

```
0 / 32767 = 0

255 / 32767 = 0.007 ~= 0
```

Либо у вас очень специфичная звуковая дорожка, либо вы что-то перепутали, `Pitch` должен сгладить эту ошибку перевода, но на "скорость" он никак не должен влиять.

---

Фрагмент, помеченный `??? endian` - **один из** вариантов перевода, я не знаю, в каком порядке ваша библиотека записывает байты, меняйте местами `leastSigByte` с `mostSigByte` по своей ситуации.

```
    private static float[] Convert16BitByteArrayToAudioClipData(byte[] source) {
        float[] buffer = new float[source.Length / 2];

        int normalizationValue = Int32.MaxValue;
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++) {
            // ??? endian
            var sampleByteIndex = i * 2;
            var leastSigByte = source[sampleByteIndex];
            var mostSigByte = source[sampleByteIndex + 1] << 8;
            // ??? endian

            buffer[i] = (float)(mostSigByte + leastSigByte) / normalizationValue;
        }

        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: да, в итоге я выяснил, что проблема была в конвертации. Но у меня решение получилось таким https://gist.github.com/alekseytimoshchenko/1cebccf6b0f54bde56dde2df36821c9c, оно немного отличается от вашего. Я проверил решение из ответа почему то я не слышу совсем ничего. Но в любом случае если добавите в ответ, то отмечу как верное. Спасибо

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko забыл скастить к float'у при делении, поэтому в результате был 0. Исправил ответ.